# How to use the Vault AppRole in our Terraform code to fetch the secrets

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, vault

I tried few online codes for fetching the secrets from Vault by using the Vault AppRole but I was not able to achieve it. Please help me get rid of this. Also, I am using Vault UI by port forwarding method.

```
terraform{
required_providers {
    vault = {
      source = "hashicorp/vault"
      version = "3.19.0"
    }
  }
}


resource "vault_approle_auth_backend" "approle_auth" {
  path = "approle"
}

resource "vault_approle_auth_backend_role" "my_approle" {
  backend   = vault_approle_auth_backend.approle_auth.path
  role_name = "xyx"
}

data "vault_approle_auth_method_login" "generate_token" {
  backend   = vault_approle_auth_backend.approle_auth.path
  role_name = vault_approle_auth_backend_role.my_approle.role_name
  secret_id = vault_approle_auth_method_role_secret_id.generate_secret_id.secret_id
}

provider "vault" {
  address = "http://localhost:8200"
  token   = data.vault_approle_auth_method_login.generate_token.client_token
}


data "vault_generic_secret" "my_secret" {
  path = "xyz"
}

output "password_value" {
  sensitive = true
  value     = data.vault_generic_secret.my_secret.data["password"]
}

output "username_value" {
  sensitive = true
  value     = data.vault_generic_secret.my_secret.data["username"]
}
```